# How to apply "non-unified diff"?

Tags: linux, diff, patch

If I create a non-unified diff like so

```
diff original.txt edited.txt > 1.patch
cp original.txt test.txt
```

I suppose that the first filename should be the untouched/original file, and the second how the original should look after the patch?

How do I then apply the patch to `test.txt`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is as simple as

```
patch test.txt 1.patch
```